# Why does Python tell me "input(' ') ValueError: could not convert string to float" when converting user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print('Input a list of numbers to do statistics on them. Type stop to end the list.')

while True:
    number_list = []
    stop_input = False

    while stop_input == False:
        user_input = input('-> ')

        if float(user_input):
            number_list.append(user_input)                    

        elif user_input == 'stop':
            stop_input = True

    print('Sum:', sum(number_list))
```

The error is as follows:

if float(user_input):

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'stop' (line 10).

I am typing input in as

1.0

2.0

3.0

stop

Comment: A couple of things: you don't need to compare with boolean, that's the point. Just do `if not stop_input` instead of `if stop_input == False`. Moreover, your error comes from your input: if you try to enter letters, the function to convert your input to float (a decimal number) will fail. So you need to either catch the exception, or change your logic.

Comment: `float("Not a float literal")` will raise an exception, not return `False`. You'll have to catch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float('stop')` will raise an exception that you have to [catch](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) with a `try: ... except ...: ...` block.

Additionally, `float(user_input)` evaluates to `False` when `user_input` is `0.0` (or `0`), so that number would never be added to the list.

You can change:

```
if float(user_input):
    number_list.append(user_input)

elif user_input == 'stop':
    stop_input = True
```

to:

```
try:
    number_list.append(float(user_input))
except ValueError:
    if user_input == 'stop':
        stop_input = True
```

to fix your program.

Comment: Just want to add that the Boolean type is a subclass of the int class ([since Python 2.3](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-bool.html)). That's why `float(user_input)` evaluates to `False` in an if-statement when it's value is 0.